# orwhereNotIn() in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using `Laravel Framework 6.16.0` and I am having the following eloquent query:

```
            $symbols = Company::select('*')
                ->leftJoin('prices', 'companies.id', '=', 'prices.companies_id')
                ->whereNotIn('companies.id', Price::select('companies_id')->get()->toArray())
                ->whereNotIn('companies.symbol', APIFound::select('generic_identifier')->get()->toArray())
                ->limit(1000)
                ->get();
```

This should represent the following sql query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    companies c
LEFT JOIN prices p ON
    c.id = p.companies_id
WHERE
    c.id NOT IN(
    SELECT
        p.companies_id
    FROM
        prices p
) OR c.symbol NOT IN(
    SELECT
        f.generic_identifier
    FROM
        a_p_i_founds f
)
```

However, I get an `and` between my `whereNotIn()`  function. How to get an `or()`?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: you can use orWhereNotIn or where clause or you can also see this refereence https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#parameter-grouping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use (where) with function:

```
 $symbols = Company::select('*')
            ->leftJoin('prices', 'companies.id', '=', 'prices.companies_id')
            ->where(function ($query)
            {
                $query->whereNotIn('companies.id', Price::select('companies_id')->get()->toArray());
            })
          ->orWhere(function ($query){
              $query->whereNotIn('companies.symbol', APIFound::select('generic_identifier')->get()->toArray());
          })
            ->limit(1000)
            ->get();
```